# Tic-Tac-Toe, how to link a 2D gameboard array with a grid?

Tags: arrays, loops, grid, location, 2d

So my problem is I want to make a modular tic tac toe game. Currently I am able to generate a grid based off player input, and rotate turns when the grid is clicked. What I haven't been able to figure out though is the logic for winning beyond hammering out the win options for a 3x3 board. Once the board becomes 5x5 or 10x10, that method becomes impossible.

Therefore I would like to use a 2D array to represent the gameboard, and connect that to the grid.

```
const grid = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  grid.push(Array(5).fill(0));
}
```

Once `grid` is generated though, and said array is created, I have no idea how to connect the two.

Here is what the grid looks like on my playcode, with no win logic, just purely visual.
https://playcode.io/686365/

Comment: Followed your link and got: `error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`.

Comment: Are you creating a 5x5 tic-tac-toe?

Comment: @iAmOren I would like to create an any size board that has win/loss logic for n. I have only given options for 3,5,10 as of now. Also I'm unsure, the link works for me.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work for me.
Logic: borrowing from what I know about "regular" tic-tac-toe: conquer the center square(s), a couple of corners (the more = the better), keep taking squares that will give you two-way options, yet, don't forget to block the opponent...
That's about all I can think of.